# LibGDX BoundingBox + pickRay issue

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been following [this](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/interacting-with-3d-objects/) tutorial for trying to be able to detect if I have clicked on a 3D model, but am running into some issues.

Here's what I have —

```
public GameObject getObject (int screenX, int screenY) {
    Ray ray = perspectiveCamera.getPickRay(screenX, screenY);
    GameObject result = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < modelInstanceArray.size; ++i) {
        final GameObject selectedModelInstance = modelInstanceArray.get(i);

        if (Intersector.intersectRayBounds(ray, selectedModelInstance.boundingBox, null)) {
            result = selectedModelInstance;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    getObject(screenX, screenY);
    return true;
}
```

.. where `GameObject` extends `ModelInstance` in order to get the `calculateBoundingBox(new BoundingBox()).mul(this.transform)` of the modelInstance as it's being.. err.. *instanced*.

When I print `ray` I get something along the lines of —

```
ray [(1.7015453E-4,8.619284E-4,1.0):(1.8586617E-4,-1.0,0.0)]
```

Which seems very.. small? I'm not sure if this looks correct or not..

My bounding box is correct, it prints as —

```
[(-120.62405,-197.27795,-57.81021)|(147.17102,202.70493,42.185677)]
```

But getObject is *always* returning the (only, for now) object in the Array, so something is going wrong. I feel like it's an issue with my `Ray`, but I'm not sure what it's *supposed* to look like.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the code of all my tutorials are available and I regularly verify that they still work. So you probably changed something. Compare your code with the code of the tutorial and check where it differs. https://github.com/xoppa/blog/tree/master/tutorials/src/com/xoppa/blog/libgdx/g3d/raypicking. Otherwise you'll have to provide more code.

Comment: hi Xoppa– thanks for responding. I've been using your tutorial, however using Intersector.intersectRaySphere would be inaccurate in my case as my model is a rather tall rectangular box-shape. All my code is nearly identical from your tutorial but I need to use a different type of bounding box, which I think is causing my issue..

Comment: read the next tutorial, which shows exactly that. https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-collision-shapes/

Comment: Are you calling `perspectiveCamera.update()`?